# my first linux script won't run

Tags: permissions, script

I am trying to write my first linux script (running on chromebook in devmode). Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'
```

This is stored in `~/Downloads/app/run`. When I try to run it I get the following:

```
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/app $ ./run
bash: ./run: Permission denied
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/app $ chmod 700 ./run
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/app $ ./run
bash: ./run: Permission denied
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/app $ sudo chmod 700 ./run

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/app $ ./run
bash: ./run: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

Command will make script executable.

then run script with:

```
./<filename>
```

Comment: Additionally, you can check the permissions of your script using `ls -l run`. Try running that before and after `chmod +x run` to see how the permission change.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the permission in the parents folders?

You should have execution permissions on these folders, for example 755.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to check with your local system admin on how to get scripts to run.

This is how it should work, when you have control:

```
$ cat >run
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'
^D

$ cat ./run 
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'

$ chmod 755 ./run 

$ ./run 
hello world

$
```